# Perl Transform values into a table

Tags: javascript, html, perl

We ask me of from the drag and the drop which I have created, to get back the values inserted by the user, but as I am new on Perl, I do not see how can it be done?:/

On the other hand, I have to post these values in the form of a table.

The function to find these values begins from `foreach my param ( @params ) {.............. }`

My person in charge advises me to match these values

```
Ex: VAR1 [

' Titre-1 ' = > 'Test'
```

.............. And so on.

```
Code JS:
```

```js
var counter = 0;

    document.addEventListener("dragstart", function(event) {
        // The dataTransfer.setData() method sets the data type and the value of the dragged data
        event.dataTransfer.setData("Text", event.target.id);

        // Output some text when starting to drag the label element
        document.getElementById("action").innerHTML = "Vous avez glissé votre élément !";

        // Change the opacity of the draggable element
        event.target.style.opacity = "0.4";
        save = event;
        setTimeout(function() {
            document.getElementById('action').innerHTML = ""; }, 2500);
        });

    // While dragging the label element, change the color of the output text
    document.addEventListener("drag", function(event) {
        document.getElementById("action").style.color = "#CD5C5C";
    });

    // Output some text when finished dragging the label element and reset the opacity
    document.addEventListener("dragend", function(event) {
        if(event.target.className == "drop-target") {
            document.getElementById("action").innerHTML = "Vous avez bien déposé votre élément !";
        }
       /* else if(event.target.className == "drop-target-Titre") {
            document.getElementById("action").innerHTML = "Vous avez bien déposé votre titre !";
        }
        else if(event.target.className == "drop-target-Message") {
            document.getElementById("action").innerHTML = "Vous avez bien déposé votre message !";
        }
        else if(event.target.className == "drop-target-Image") {
            document.getElementById("action").innerHTML = "Vous avez bien déposé votre image !";
        }
        else if(event.target.className == "drop-target-Lien") {
            document.getElementById("action").innerHTML = "Vous avez bien déposé votre lien !";
        }*/
        event.target.style.opacity = "1";
        document.getElementById("action").style.color = "#CD5C5C";

        setTimeout(function() {
            document.getElementById('action').innerHTML = ""; }, 2500);
    });


    /* Events fired on the drop target */

    // When the draggable label element enters the droptarget, change the DIVS's border style
    document.addEventListener("dragenter", function(event) {
        if ( event.target.className == "drop-target") {
            event.target.style.border = "3px dotted #483D8B";
        }
        else if(event.target.className == "drop-target-1") {
            event.target.style.border = "3px dotted #483D8B";
            document.getElementById("action").innerHTML = "Vous êtes au bon endroit pour insérer votre élément ! ";
        }
        else if(event.target.className == "drop-target-2") {
            event.target.style.border = "3px dotted #483D8B";
            document.getElementById("action").innerHTML = "Vous êtes au bon endroit pour insérer votre élément ! ";
        }
        else if(event.target.className == "drop-target-3") {
            event.target.style.border = "3px dotted #483D8B";
            document.getElementById("action").innerHTML = "Vous êtes au bon endroit pour insérer votre élément ! ";
        }
        else if(event.target.className == "drop-target-4") {
            event.target.style.border = "3px dotted #483D8B";
            document.getElementById("action").innerHTML = "Vous êtes au bon endroit pour insérer votre élément ! ";
        }
        else if(event.target.className == "drop-target-phone" && save.target.id == "numtel") {
            event.target.style.border = "3px dotted #483D8B";
            document.getElementById("action").innerHTML = "Vous êtes au bon endroit pour insérer votre n° de téléphone !";
        }
        else if (event.target.className == "drop-target-mail" && save.target.id == "mail") {
            event.target.style.border = "3px dotted #483D8B";
            document.getElementById("action").innerHTML = "Vous êtes au bon endroit pour insérer votre mail !";
        }
        else if(event.target.className == "drop-target-contact" && save.target.id == "contact") {
            event.target.style.border = "3px dotted #483D8B";
            document.getElementById("action").innerHTML = "Vous êtes au bon endroit pour insérer votre nom et prénom !";
        }

        setTimeout(function() {
            document.getElementById('action').innerHTML = ""; }, 2500);
    });

    // By default, data/elements cannot be dropped in other elements. To allow a drop, we must prevent the default handling of the element
    document.addEventListener("dragover", function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
    });

    // When the draggable label element leaves the droptarget, reset the DIVS's border style
    document.addEventListener("dragleave", function(event) {
        if(event.target.className == "drop-target") {
            event.target.style.border = "";
        }
        else if(event.target.className == "drop-target-1") {
            event.target.style.border = "";
        }
        else if(event.target.className == "drop-target-2") {
            event.target.style.border = "";
        }
        else if(event.target.className == "drop-target-3") {
            event.target.style.border = "";
        }
        else if(event.target.className == "drop-target-4") {
            event.target.style.border = "";
        }
        else if (event.target.className == "drop-target-phone") {
            event.target.style.border = "";
        }
        else if (event.target.className == "drop-target-mail") {
            event.target.style.border = "";
        }
        else if (event.target.className == "drop-target-contact") {
            event.target.style.border = "";
        }
    });

    /* On drop - Prevent the browser default handling of the data (default is open as link on drop)
       Reset the color of the output text and DIV's border color
       Get the dragged data with the dataTransfer.getData() method
       The dragged data is the id of the dragged element ("drag1")
       Append the dragged element into the drop element
    */
    /*document.addEventListener("drop", function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        if ( event.target.className == "drop-target-Titre" ) {
            document.getElementById("action").style.color = "";
            event.target.style.border = "";       
            var data = event.dataTransfer.getData("Text");
                switch (data) {
                    case 'Titre':
                        $('.drop-target').append("<div class='col-sm-12' droppable='false' id='deletetitle"+ counter+"' ondblclick='supprimer(this,\"titre\")'> <span style='font-style: italic; margin-right: 5%; font-size: 16px'>Votre titre :</span> <input type='text' name='TitreCli' style='margin-right: 25%; width: 250px; height: 30px; background-color: #F5F5DC'></input></div>");
                        break;
                    case 'Texte':
                        $('.drop-target').append("<div class='col-sm-12' droppable='false' id='deletetext"+ counter+"' ondblclick='supprimer(this,\"texte\")'> <span style='font-style: italic; margin-right: 15%; font-size: 16px;'>Votre message : </span> <textarea name='MessageCli' style='margin-right: 25%; max-height: 50px; max-width: 500px; background-color: #F5F5DC'></textarea></div>");
                        break;
                    case 'Image':
                        $('.drop-target').append("<div class='col-sm-12' droppable='false' id='deleteimage"+ counter+"' ondblclick='supprimer(this,\"image\")'> <span style='font-style: italic; margin-right: 24.5%; font-size: 16px'>Votre image : </span> <input type='text' name='ImageCli' style='margin-right: 25%; background-color: #F5F5DC'></input><div>");
                        break;
                    case 'Lien':
                        $('.drop-target').append("<div class='col-sm-12' droppable='false' id='deletelink"+ counter+"' ondblclick='supprimer(this,\"lien\")'> <span style='font-style: italic; margin-right: 40%; font-size: 16px'> Votre lien : </span> <input type='text' name='LienCli' style='margin-left: -12%; margin-right: 20%; background-color: #F5F5DC'></input><div>");
                        break;
                }
            counter ++;
        }
                
        });*/

    document.addEventListener("drop", function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        if(event.target.className == "drop-target-1") {
            $('.drop-target-1').append("<div class='col-sm-12' droppable='false' id='"+ save.target.id +"-1' ondblclick='deleteContents(this,\"" + save.target.id+"\")'> <span>Votre " + save.target.id +" :</span> <input type='text' id='"+ save.target.id +"-1'></input></div>");
        }
        else if(event.target.className == "drop-target-2") {
            $('.drop-target-2').append("<div class='col-sm-12' droppable='false' id='"+ save.target.id +"-2' ondblclick='deleteContents(this,\"" + save.target.id+"\")'> <span>Votre " + save.target.id +" :</span> <input id='"+ save.target.id+"-2'></input></div>");
        }
        else if(event.target.className == "drop-target-3") {
            $('.drop-target-3').append("<div class='col-sm-12' droppable='false' id='"+ save.target.id+"-3' ondblclick='deleteContents(this,\"" + save.target.id+"\")'> <span>Votre " + save.target.id+" :</span> <input type='text' id='"+ save.target.id+"-3'></input></div>");
        }
        else if(event.target.className == "drop-target-4") {
            $('.drop-target-4').append("<div class='col-sm-12' droppable='false' id='"+ save.target.id+"-4' ondblclick='deleteContents(this,\"" + save.target.id+"\")'> <span>Votre "+ save.target.id+" :</span> <input type='text' id='"+ save.target.id+"-4'></input></div>");
        }
        else if (event.target.className == "drop-target-phone" && save.target.id == "numtel") {
            $('.drop-target-phone').append("<div class='col-sm-4' droppable='false' id='telcli' ondblclick='deleteContents(this,\"téléphone\")' style='width: 175px; height: 80px;'> <span style='font-style: italic; margin-right: 8%; font-size: 16px; text-align: center'> Téléphone :</span> <input type='text' id='telcli' style='margin-right: 5%; width: 150px; height: 30px; background-color: #F5F5DC'></input></div>");
        }
        else if (event.target.className == "drop-target-mail" && save.target.id == "mail") {
            $('.drop-target-mail').append("<div class='col-sm-4' droppable='false' id='mailcli' ondblclick='deleteContents(this,\"mail\")' style='width: 175px; height: 80px'> <span style='font-style: italic; margin-right: 8%; font-size: 16px; text-align: center'> Mail :</span> <input type='text' id='mailcli' style='margin-right: 5%; width: 150px; height: 30px; background-color: #F5F5DC'></input></div>");
        }
        else if (event.target.className == "drop-target-contact" && save.target.id == "contact") {
            $('.drop-target-contact').append("<div class='col-sm-4' droppable='false' id='contactcli' ondblclick='deleteContents(this,\"contact\")' style='width: 175px; height: 80px'> <span style='font-style: italic; margin-right: 8%; font-size: 16px; text-align: center'> Contact :</span> <input type='text' id='contactcli' style='margin-right: 5%; width: 150px; height: 30px; background-color: #F5F5DC'></input></div>");
        };
        event.target.style.border = "";
    });

    function deleteContents(nom, argument) {
        $(nom).remove();
        document.getElementById("action").innerHTML = "Vous avez bien supprimé votre " +argument+" !";
        setTimeout(function() {
            document.getElementById("action").innerHTML = ""; }, 2500);
        };

/*function preview() {
        var toPrint = document.getElementById('previewarea');
        var popupWin = window.open('', '_blank', 'width=400,height=700,location=no,left=200px');
        
        popupWin.document.open();
    popupWin.document.write('<html><title>::PrintPreview::</title><body><p>Vos données ont bien été enregistrées !</p></body">');
        popupWin.document.write('</html>');
        popupWin.document.close();
    }*/

function preview(url) {
regex pour le téléphone /^[(]{0,1}[0-9]{3}[)]{0,1}[-\s\.]{0,1}[0-9]{3}[-\s\.]{0,1}[0-9]{4}$/; */

    var myData = {
        'rm':'previewZone',
};

        var list = document.getElementById("drop-target");
        var y = list.getElementsByTagName("input");
        /*var x = list.getElementsByTagName("textarea");
        for (i=0; i <x.length; i++)
        {
            if(x[i].id)
            {
                myData[x[i].id] = x[i].value;
                /*result = x[i].value;*/
            /*}
        }*/
        for (var i in y)
        {
            if(y[i].id)
            {
                myData[y[i].id] = y[i].value;
            }
        }
console.log(myData);
    $.post(url,myData).done(function(data)
    {
        var popupWin = window.open('', '_blank', 'width=400,height=700,location=no,left=200px');
        popupWin.document.open();
        popupWin.document.write('<html><title>::PrintPreview::</title><body><p>Vos données ont bien été enregistrées !</p></body">');
        popupWin.document.write('</html>');
        popupWin.document.close();
        });
}
```

Code Perl:

```
sub previewZone
{
    my $self = shift;

    my $query = $self->query;

    my $session = $self->param('session');
    my $profile = $session->param('profile');

    my $User = User->newFromId($profile->{'uid'});
    if($User eq 'NOT_FOUND')
    {
        return $self->redirect('index.pl?rm=notfound');
    }

    my @params = $query->param();

    my %hash ();

    foreach my $param  (@params)
    {
       if($param =~ /([a-zA-Z]*)\-(\d)/)
       {
          my $field = $1;
          my $number = $2;
          $hash{$number}->{$field} = scalar $query->param($param) ;
      }
    }

print %hash;

***my $fnret = _formatModelPart(
            'data' => $data2,
            'part' => $part
        );***

   if($fnret eq 'FILE_NOT_FOUND' or $fnret eq 'FAILURE' or $fnret eq 'NO_DATA')
   {
      return $self->redirect('index.pl?rm=notfound');
   }


    #foreach ( my ($key, $value) = each @params) {
    #   print @params, $key . ' => '. $value;
    #}

    $log->info(Dumper(\@params));
}
```

Comment: It's only in english here. If you want to communicate in french, you can go to https://www.developpez.net/forums/

Comment: Oh damn sorry, I will edit my problem ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line gets all the parameter keys from the query

```
my @params = $query->param();
```

and `$query->param("Titre-1")` would get the value for your example parameter, so one of the ways you could populate your hash is

```
foreach my $param (@params)
{
    $hash{$param}=$query->param($param);
}
```

If you want to group by the parameters by the number at the end of them you can use a regular expression to capture the number and the field name like this and then store the parameter value in a hash of hashes.

```
if($param =~ /^(.*)-(\d+)$/)
{
    my $field=$1;
    my $number=$2;

    $hash{$number}->{$field}=$query->param($param);
}
```

and for a query string that looked like `Title-1=Something&File-1=something.txt`, you would get a data structure like

```
$VAR1 = {
          '1' => {
                   'Title' => 'Something',
                   'File' => 'something.txt'
                 }
        };
```

Comment: Thx for ur help Chris! I'm gonna check this right now :)

Comment: What I would like to do now, it's to post these values in a hash, in a hash, by saving the number of the element. For example

Comment: A hash of hash looks like `$hash{$somekey}->{$someotherkey}=$somevalue;`, but you've only got a key & value. you're missing the second key

Comment: What I would like to do now, it's to post these values in a hash, in a hash, by saving the number of the element. For example, { 1 => {type => "Titre", value => "Test"} ...........}  Do u have any solution please? Maybe, my problem is simple to resolve, but I am new in Perl and I don't master still well tables :/

Comment: Not entirely sure what your input is going to look like, but I've expanded my answer to include a way of grouping by the number element of the parameter

Comment: Hum yeah thanks again for ur answer ! So, if I edit my code like u said me, $field will take the value of my key (for example: "Message") and $number will take the number of the key ?

Comment: Oh ok thx, and this will be my last question, how $field and $number will recover the  value and the number key??  And to what correspond $1 and $2 on the declaration of variables please??

Comment: `$1` and `$2` are from the regular expression - they match the 2 capture groups in it

Comment: Good, ok I understood, I really need to practice, good and fast Perl ! :) Thanks a lot for your simply answers Chris and for taking the time to answer me!! ;)  Would it be possible to come back to you in the next weeks even next days in case of problem with Perl?

Comment: Just create a new question on here, I'm sure I or one of the other perl coders will see it and be able to help

Comment: Ok no problem I will do it ;) Thanks again and have a nice day ! :)

Comment: Hello again everyone, I'm still working on this code, and now the maintainer is asking me to manage data through %hash and to allow a redirection. The maintanier advices me to manage it into a %hash my $fnret = _formatModelPart(
    'data' => $data2,
    'part' => $part
   );                                                                                               It's the code I have to work on.